# Grails own plugin error ActiveMQ

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy

i'm creating my own plugin for integration services, but when i insert it on the project, i have a  error. Why the app is throwing this exception?

> Error Fatal error during compilation org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:

[BuildConfig]

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 1024, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 1024, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 1024, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        //grailsHome()

        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()

        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
        compile('org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0',
                'org.apache.activemq:activeio-core:3.1.4',
                'org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:3.17') {
                excludes 'activemq-openwire-generator'
                excludes 'commons-logging'
                excludes 'xalan'
                excludes 'xml-apis'
                exported = false
       }
    }

    plugins {
        build(":release:3.0.1",
              ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
            export = false
        }
        compile ":jms:1.3"

    }
}
```

[Plugin descriptor]

```
def doWithSpring = {
        jmsConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory) {
            brokerURL = "tcp://localhost:61616"
        }
    }
```

Error message

```
ExpediaGrailsPlugin.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
```

Comment: I had the same issue and ended up having to add this in my BuildConfig.groovy: compile ('org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:5.5.1'). Looking at the dependencies.groovy in the jms plugin, it looks like it only includes the ActiveMQ dependencies with the test scope. So, it makes sense that they're not showing up. I'm not sure why they are not including those dependencies though - there must be some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Remove exported = false and it will work. To be honest I do not understand why. As soon as exported = false is added, activemq-core is missing in the dependency report.

Comment: But exported = false not add the dependency in app it have installed the plugin, but in (just) the plugin thats works fine! When i install it in my app an expetion is throwed. But, thanks for reply!